# p5.js sprite movement back and forth

Tags: sprite, p5.js

Hi all I am in need of some help. I am working on a project and would like my enemy sprite to move back end forth for a specific distance. I have manged to get him to flip from right to left, then after that he disappears. I am sure there is something wrong with my conditional statement (or maybe I may need a loop) please help.

```
if(enemystart <= 0 && enemystart >= -100)
    {
        enemystart = enemystart + (enemyspeed * enemydirection * -1);
        image(zombieL[frameCount % 10], enemystart, floorPos_y - 58, 60, 60); 
    }
else if(enemyp1 >= -100 && enemyp1 <= 0)
    {
        enemyp1 = enemyp1 + (enemyspeed * enemydirection);
        image(zombie[frameCount % 10], enemyp1, floorPos_y - 58, 60, 60);
    }
```

Comment: Please post a complete example of your code, preferably reduced to the minimal amount of code needed to reproduce your issue/demonstrate your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't change the enemydirection variable. Change it to 90 on turning right and -90 on turning left. And also 0 on turning towards top and 180 on turning bottom. This might solve the problem? I guess so!

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.